# Socket.io on connect event fails to fire sometimes / Write a better socket.io wrapper

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, reactjs

I am upgrading a traditional jquery based app by converting a few parts of it into ReactJs components and use socket.io for the data transfer medium.

There are a few React components spread across the page.
The react components will receive updates from the socket connection in their `componentDidMount` method.

for example :

```
componentDidMount: function(){
    socket.on('connect', function(data){....});
    socket.on('anotherEvent', function(data){....})
}
```

Now, the thing is that the React components will be scattered across the page and will not be under a single app structure, and they will be subscribing to the same socket events to stay in sync.

For this, I wrote the below socket.io wrapper, this way multiple subscriptions for the same events can be avoided but all the interested React components can be notified on an event update.

```
window.socketEvents = (function(){
    var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000"),
        events = {};                    //events structure = {'event_name':subscribers:[callback functions], isSubscribed:true}

    var _register = function(event, callback){
        events[event] = events[event] || {};
        events[event].subscribers = events[event].subscribers || [];
        events[event].subscribers.push(callback);
    };

    var _subscribe = function(event){
        console.log('Subscribingto: ', event);
        socket.on(event, function(data){    // notifiy the subscribers of this event by firing their callbacks.
            for(var cb=0;cb<events[event].subscribers.length;cb++){
                events[event].subscribers[cb](data);
            };
        });
        events[event].isSubscribed = true;
    };  

    var emit = function(event, data){
        socket.emit(event, data);
    };

    return {
        listen: function(event, callback){
            _register(event, callback);
            if(!events[event].isSubscribed){
                _subscribe(event);
            };
        },
        emit: emit
    }

})();
```

React Example with the new wrapper:

In ReactClassOne:

```
componentDidMount: function(){
    socketEvents.listen('connect', function(data){...});
    socketEvents.listen('anotherEvent', function(data){...})
}
```

In ReactClassTwo:

```
componentDidMount: function(){
    socketEvents.listen('connect', function(data){...})
    socketEvents.listen('anotherEvent', function(data){...})
}
```

**Issue:** Everything works as expected but sometimes the `connect` events fails to fire. This happens intermittently.

I understand that I am not able to figure out the `connect` part properly in my app, Also, `connect` might have to be fired only once on the page and not in every component.

Can someone help me with my design issue. Thanks!